# Unable to access internet on pod in private GKE cluster

Tags: linux-networking, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm currently unable to access/ping/connect to any service outside of Google from my private Kubernetes cluster. The pods are running Alpine linux.

**Routing Tables**

```
/sleepez/api # ip route show table all
default via 10.52.1.1 dev eth0
10.52.1.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 10.52.1.4
broadcast 10.52.1.0 dev eth0 table local scope link  src 10.52.1.4
local 10.52.1.4 dev eth0 table local scope host  src 10.52.1.4
broadcast 10.52.1.255 dev eth0 table local scope link  src 10.52.1.4
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo table local scope link  src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local scope host  src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local scope host  src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local scope link  src 127.0.0.1
local ::1 dev lo  metric 0
local fe80::ac29:afff:fea1:9357 dev lo  metric 0
fe80::/64 dev eth0  metric 256
ff00::/8 dev eth0  metric 256
unreachable default dev lo  metric -1  error -101
```

The pod certainly has an assigned IP and has no problem connecting to it's gateway:

```
PS C:\...\> kubectl get pods -o wide -n si-dev
NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP          NODE
sleep-intel-api-79bf57bd9-c4l8d   1/1       Running   0          52m       10.52.1.4   gke-sez-production-default-pool-74b75ebc-6787
```

**`ip addr` output**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0@if7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1460 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 0a:58:0a:34:01:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.52.1.4/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ac29:afff:fea1:9357/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Pinging Gateway Works**

```
/sleepez/api # ping 10.52.1.1
PING 10.52.1.1 (10.52.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.52.1.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.111 ms
64 bytes from 10.52.1.1: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.148 ms
64 bytes from 10.52.1.1: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.137 ms
^C
--- 10.52.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.111/0.132/0.148 ms
```

**Pinging 1.1.1.1 Fails**

```
/sleepez/api # ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

**System Services Status**

```
PS C:\...\> kubectl get deploy -n kube-system
NAME                    DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
event-exporter-v0.1.7   1         1         1            1           18m
heapster-v1.4.3         1         1         1            1           18m
kube-dns                2         2         2            2           18m
kube-dns-autoscaler     1         1         1            1           18m
l7-default-backend      1         1         1            1           18m
tiller-deploy           1         1         1            1           14m
```

**Traceroute (Google Internal)**

```
/sleepez/api # traceroute -In 74.125.69.105
 1  10.52.1.1  0.007 ms  0.006 ms  0.006 ms
 2  *  *  *
 3  *  *  *
 4  *  *
```

**Traceroute (External)**

```
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  10.52.1.1  0.009 ms  0.003 ms  0.004 ms
 2  *  *  *
 3  *  *  *
 [continues...]
```

Comment: Including a traceroute from the VM to an IP address outside of Google as well as a traceroute from outside of Google to the external IP address of your VM will make this problem a lot easier to debug.

Comment: @kasperd I included the traceroutes from inside the pod to an internal Google. I'm not sure how the external traceroute will help since it terminates at the Google-managed K8s cluster...

Comment: The other traceroute I was asking for was from an external network to the external IP address of your VM.

Comment: With a private GKE cluster the Compute nodes don't receive an external IP address. I can add one to provide the debugging info, but I still doubt that that is the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nodes in a private GKE cluster do not have external IP addresses, so they cannot communicate with sites outside of Google. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#pulling_a_container_image_from_a_registry

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer and I wish this was highlighted a bit more in their documentation.

Comment: u should use a nat gateway like Cloud NAT to redirect traffic in ur VPC through it. the cloud NAT runs outside ur cluster but on the same network.

Comment: @Tarek could you please provide the steps to enable NAT on private GKE.

Comment: In retrospect to this question, I'm dumb, but I hope it helps others.

Comment: @k_vishwanath I added the steps to enable NAT on private GKE.

Answer (score 0):

I have two private gke clusters currently accessing the internet now. I thought I achieved this by using the NAT Gateway but adding a third cluster now it is not working for the third cluster. I suspect it's a difference in versions in kubernetes on the clusters.

Without question your other private ip'd servers/nodes can access your private cluster through services and your pods can access the internet through (I think) NAT.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished debugging this in a lab cluster.

Test Driven Development says you should come up with a test first.

**1st test of internet access from private GKE node:**

1. In the GCP Console GUI you can select ssh to private node through the browser (Even if the GKE node only has a private IP, and there's no Bastion Host, or NAT/Internet Gateway), it didn't work for me until I ran the following that I derived from some docs.
2. `gcloud compute --project=$PROJECT firewall-rules create ssh-from-browser --direction=INGRESS --priority=500 --network=lab-vpc --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:22 --source-ranges=35.235.240.0/20`
3. After the above firewall rule I created a new ssh browser session and it worked (the original ssh browser session from before I added the rule continued to fail for some reason.)
4. Internet test via GKE node based on COS:
   `curl ifconfig.me`
   (It hung / eventually timed out, ping isn't installed)

**2nd test of internet access from GKE pod:**

```shell
alias k=kubectl
k run -it busybox --image=busybox -- /bin/sh
exit
k exec -it busybox -- ping 8.8.8.8
```

The ping hangs until use ctrl+c to break out, and you'll see a mention of 100% packet loss (so no internet)

---

---

**The following doc has a "Requirements, restrictions, and limitations" section that explains that Cloud NAT is needed:**
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#req_res_lim

> In a private cluster, nodes only have internal IP addresses, which
> means that nodes and Pods are isolated from the internet by default.
> ...
> All nodes in a private cluster are created without a public IP;
> they have limited access to Google APIs and services. To provide
> outbound internet access for your private nodes, you can use Cloud
> NAT.

---

---

**Here's the solution I came up with:**
Most of the solution is derived from here   https://gist.github.com/mikesparr/9f522b00b4d3c32227b2ae179260c6e4

```
export NETWORK_NAME="lab-vpc"
export GCP_REGION="us-central1"
export CLOUD_ROUTER_NAME="router-1"
export CLOUD_ROUTER_ASN="64523"
export NAT_GW_NAME="nat-gateway-1"

gcloud compute routers create $CLOUD_ROUTER_NAME \
    --network $NETWORK_NAME \
    --asn $CLOUD_ROUTER_ASN \
    --region $GCP_REGION

gcloud compute routers nats create $NAT_GW_NAME \
 --router=$CLOUD_ROUTER_NAME \
 --region=$GCP_REGION \
 --auto-allocate-nat-external-ips \
 --nat-all-subnet-ip-ranges
```

---

---

**The Two Internet Access Tests will now work**
**1st Internet test via GKE node (SSH'd through GCP Console GUI):**
Private-GKE-Node-Bash ~ $ `curl ifconfig.me`
(Now lists the WAN IP of the NAT Gateway)

**2nd Internet test via GKE pod:**

```shell
alias k=kubectl
k exec -it busybox -- ping 8.8.8.8
```

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=114 time=1.394 ms
(infinite loop until ctrl+c to break out)

Both tests confirm internet after the change